# How to set the width of columns of a table correct in HTML?

Tags: html, css

In the following html code, I have created a table. But the column width is not correct. I have added the css code also and the output image. Please tell me where I am wrong, why table column width is not equal. Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

header {
  background-color: #EC7063;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  background-color: #76D7C4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  color: #21618C;
}

#cat {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #27AE60;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}

h2 {
  color: #21618C;
}

#prod {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #AF7AC5;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #EC7063;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #F8F9F9;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>My Guitar Shop</h1>
</header>
<header>
  <h1>Product Manager</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>Product List</h1>
  <section id="cat">
    <!-- display a list of categories -->
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="?category_id=1">Guitars</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="?category_id=2">Basses</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="?category_id=3">Drums</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="?category_id=4">Flutes</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="?category_id=5">Trumpets</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <section id="prod">
    <!-- display a table of products -->
    <h2>Guitars</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>gu</td>
        <td>ytr</td>
        <td>0000000546</td>
        <td>
          <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_product" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="19" />
            <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>yui</td>
        <td>uyt</td>
        <td>0000000888</td>
        <td>
          <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_product" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="23" />
            <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>oi</td>
        <td>iu</td>
        <td>0000000098</td>
        <td>
          <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_product" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="24" />
            <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p><a href="?action=show_add_form">Add Product</a></p>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>&copy; 2017 My Guitar Shop, Inc.</p>
</footer>
```

[image]

Comment: try removing `display:block` from your table

Comment: tried that. though it set the column width correct but it doesn't help. it removes the scroll.

Comment: In case you need more help with this, please provide actually usable code - meaning the resulting HTML, not PHP code that no one here will be able to properly execute on their system even if they tried. [mcve]

Comment: Put the table in a div with a set height and put the scroll on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the table in a div and give the `max-height` and `overflow: scroll` to that div . It easy 
Codepen link
https://codepen.io/yashagw/pen/wezzVj

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width from css

```
th, td {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for table, td and th

```
table {
 overflow: auto;
 table-layout: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td, table tr th{
 width:1%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align: center;
}
```

you can't use height and display block for table.

Comment: table {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100px;
   }

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}

table tr td, table tr th{
 width:1%;
 
}

Comment: what exactly table tr td, table tr th { width: 1%; }  does?

Comment: It's make table cells with equal.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is a table that filled 100% width and also displays a scroll bar when the content exceeds the height, then you could do the following.

First of all, **remove** the `"display: block;"` property from the css of the table. It kind of removes a lot of the inherent properties of tables and its sub-tags (tr,td,th etc).

Now, wrap the table in a div of fixed height and give the div fixed height and overflow-y properties in css, as below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-container">
   <table>
       ...table contents...
   </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Table has the following css now. */

table {
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

See **JS Fiddle**.
https://jsfiddle.net/rhk217/L4khbs2j/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `display: block;` for table. Just use default table display (table-cell) is okay.

Comment: it removes the scroll.. I want the scroll also

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `display: block;`

Try the following

```
table {
 overflow: auto;
 height: 100px;
 table-layout: fixed;
 width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: wrap table in a section and then give style to that section as overflow-x: scroll;